# X.org is allocating more than 900MB of RAM but xrestop says ~1/40th of that is actually used; how I force it to free the rest without restarting X?

Tags: xorg, ram, memory-leak

So X.org is allocating an insane amount of RAM: right now 910MB (according to the `RES` column in htop), second only to Firefox (really Nightly) (at just over 1GB) and trailed by GNOME Shell (at only 256MB). I searched online for ways to force X to free leaked memory, and what I found suggested using xrestop to spot the cause. The problem is that xrestop is saying this:

```
xrestop - Display: localhost
          Monitoring 24 clients. XErrors: 0
          Pixmaps:   21876K total, Other:     519K total, All:   22396K total
```

This clearly says that X resources are only accounting for a whopping 22MB. The other software I'm running at this time are Liferea, Konversation, and gnome-terminal with several tabs open.

You might think that Firefox is causing this, but no: if I kill that, X.org's memory stays high: now at 957MB, minutes after I initially wrote this question, and xrestop switches to

```
xrestop - Display: localhost
          Monitoring 23 clients. XErrors: 0
          Pixmaps:    9975K total, Other:     504K total, All:   10480K total
```

instead!

Now all the Google hits I found for X memory leaks that actually post xrestop output shows that the problem is clearly in resource allocation; these answers all have resource usage that nears the total RAM usage of X.org. But this isn't the case here.

Bug reports I've found are a) from 2009 b) inconclusive.

What's going on and how can I free all that extra RAM **without restarting X**? I'd rather not have to load my session (active chats, terminal tabs) over again.

Ubuntu GNOME 14.10
fglrx-updates 2:14.201-0ubuntu2 installed via Additional Drivers
Lenovo G50-45
AMD A6-6310 APU with AMD Radeon R4 Graphics
I technically have 4GB of RAM, but htop only says 3221MB is available and `free -m` says (while Firefox is still running)

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3221       3087        133          5          6        125
-/+ buffers/cache:       2955        265
Swap:         7812       2662       5150
```

My system has been up for 12 days and 4 hours now, and in that time I've also run the acme text editor, fceux, empathy, some sgt-puzzles games, and possibly other programs.

Thanks.

**UPDATE** 31 January 2015

`top -n 1` output from a few minutes ago (4:04 AM, shortly after a slowdown streak):

```
top - 04:04:19 up 14 days,  9:00,  9 users,  load average: 1.98, 2.17, 2.06
Tasks: 414 total,   2 running, 410 sleeping,   2 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 10.6 us,  2.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 85.9 id,  1.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   3298800 total,  3119652 used,   179148 free,    18796 buffers
KiB Swap:  8000508 total,  3067288 used,  4933220 free.   208568 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND     
17722 pietro    20   0 2672276 1.264g  38596 R  80.3 40.2 136:03.00 firefox-tr+ 
 1767 root      20   0 3267084 780500  79680 S  17.2 23.7   1168:42 Xorg        
17302 pietro    20   0 2122240 275544  52684 S  17.2  8.4  90:48.53 gnome-shell 
25038 pietro    20   0   29280   3064   2368 R  11.5  0.1   0:00.04 top         
    1 root      20   0   29584    920    776 S   0.0  0.0   0:09.45 init        
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.60 kthreadd    
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:21.44 ksoftirqd/0 
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:+ 
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0  31:41.83 rcu_sched   
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   6:56.03 rcuos/0     
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   6:51.16 rcuos/1     
   10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   6:45.78 rcuos/2     
   11 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0  10:45.32 rcuos/3     
   12 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh      
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/0     
   14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/1     
   15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/2
```

`top -n 1` output from just now (4:18-ish AM, during another one):

```
top - 04:19:08 up 14 days,  9:15,  9 users,  load average: 2.22, 2.04, 1.98
Tasks: 416 total,   1 running, 413 sleeping,   2 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 10.6 us,  2.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 85.9 id,  1.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   3298800 total,  3105312 used,   193488 free,     8220 buffers
KiB Swap:  8000508 total,  3064824 used,  4935684 free.   149000 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND     
17722 pietro    20   0 2745204 1.298g  30852 S  75.2 41.3 141:50.42 firefox-tr+ 
17302 pietro    20   0 2122624 217428  47028 S  11.6  6.6  93:07.81 gnome-shell 
25183 pietro    20   0   29280   3152   2456 R  11.6  0.1   0:00.04 top         
14792 pietro    20   0  166024    752    752 S   5.8  0.0   0:03.54 plumber     
    1 root      20   0   29584    916    776 S   0.0  0.0   0:09.45 init        
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.60 kthreadd    
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:21.45 ksoftirqd/0 
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:+ 
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0  31:43.49 rcu_sched   
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   6:56.52 rcuos/0     
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   6:51.66 rcuos/1     
   10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   6:46.29 rcuos/2     
   11 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0  10:46.09 rcuos/3     
   12 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh      
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/0     
   14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/1     
   15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/2
```

And one more, also just now (4:20 AM):

```
top - 04:20:59 up 14 days,  9:17,  9 users,  load average: 2.20, 2.09, 2.00
Tasks: 416 total,   2 running, 412 sleeping,   2 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 10.6 us,  2.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 85.9 id,  1.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   3298800 total,  3102064 used,   196736 free,     7196 buffers
KiB Swap:  8000508 total,  3042968 used,  4957540 free.   137692 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND     
17302 pietro    20   0 2122688 217972  47528 S  16.8  6.6  93:23.58 gnome-shell 
17722 pietro    20   0 2765140 1.289g  36856 R  16.8 41.0 142:46.71 firefox-tr+ 
25197 pietro    20   0   29280   3136   2444 R  11.2  0.1   0:00.05 top         
25200 pietro    20   0  233480   9448   8316 S  11.2  0.3   0:00.02 gpaste      
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   5.6  0.0   6:51.72 rcuos/1     
 1767 root      20   0 3260868 858068  73568 S   5.6 26.0   1169:44 Xorg        
    1 root      20   0   29584    872    776 S   0.0  0.0   0:09.45 init        
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.60 kthreadd    
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:21.46 ksoftirqd/0 
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:+ 
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0  31:43.72 rcu_sched   
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   6:56.58 rcuos/0     
   10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   6:46.34 rcuos/2     
   11 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0  10:46.21 rcuos/3     
   12 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh      
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/0     
   14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/1
```

(as requested by Fabby below)

**UPDATE** 5 February 2015

Wait, something's not right: I restarted my computer two days ago and in that time X.org has only allocated 254MB, not 900+ MB...??? xrestop says only 30MB is used. Would graphics drivers only require fixed amounts of RAM?

Comment: WHere does it say X is using 900MB? And the 4096 vs 3221 is almost certainly due to using SoC graphics, and so the graphics memory is shared with system RAM.

Comment: In the `RES` column of htop (which I'm pretty sure I pointed out above). I figured integrated graphics might have had to do with the RAM difference (given that came up in search results/related questions suggestions as well), but I didn't think it would be *that* much (unless I don't actually have 4GB...)

Comment: Okay, `dmidecode` confirms that I indeed have 4GB of RAM.

Comment: It's probably configured to use up to 1GB of RAM for video. It's currently using about 900M for video. That is probably where the "RES" of Xorg being 900M is coming from.

Comment: So are you saying the 900MB are for the integrated graphics? If so, why does htop not say 4096MB RAM available? (That is, that would mean it's allocating twice that, one for the graphics hardware and one for X.org?)

Comment: Because top reports memory addressable via program space through the CPU, not all memory. For the same reason it won't report 5GB if you disable the internal video and install a discrete card with 1GB of memory. But Xorg allocates memory via the GPU, not the CPU, for graphics, and so when top looks at the process size it sees XXX MB, but that is not all necessarily from the system RAM, but may be graphics memory accessed via hardware through GPU. At least, that is my understanding of how Xorg memory works.

Comment: All right then, thanks. I guess it's off to find out what else is causing my system's high overall memory usage until then (even without Firefox I still have quite a bit of swap used, to give an idea). Thanks anyway!

Comment: can you post the output of `top` because in there my xorg is taking 100M RAM and 500 virt on a 4Mb system comparable to yours. (but I shut down my machine at least 2*/week)

Comment: @dobey Wait, something's not right: I restarted my computer two days ago and in that time X.org has only allocated 254MB, not 900+ MB...??? (xrestop still says only 30MB is used.) Wouldn't graphics drivers require fixed amounts of RAM? (updated question)

Comment: @andlabs No. Internal SoC graphics share memory with system RAM, and may allocate up to the maximum allowed when needed.